# Objective-c SIGABRT after changing xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, sigabrt

I got the SIGABRT signal after I changed the xib file. Right after building, before I can see any window or GUI it says: "GDB: Program received signal 'SIGABRT'
Any clues? The File's owner is an empty class (that means there is nothing except for @interface, 2 curly brackets @implementation and 2 times @end) extending NSViewController.

**EDIT:**
It turned out I edited another property in the info.plist file, that was the reason I got the SIGABRT. But now, he says "Unable to load nib file: myNibFile.xib"

Comment: (Xcode 4.x is known to be screwy when it comes to reporting exceptions.)  You can usually get better information if you go to the Breakpoint Navigator window and set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.  Other tricks include wrapping the line you quoted in a @try/@catch block and printing out the exception and its stack symbols.  (Ah...I just noticed your comment but I'll post this anyway in case someone runs into the same silly Xcode behavior.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I edited accidently the "Principle class" field in the info.plist file!